# Precision recall curve: how to show the value at recall 1 when not all the relevant documents can be retrieved?

Tags: machine-learning, information-retrieval, precision-recall

I am studying the precision and recall curve.
Examples given by books show that although the result does not include all the relevant documents, the curve plots the recall value up to 1, thus indicating that all the relevant documents can be retrieved.

For example, let's say we have 10 relevant documents and 15 results that include 4 relevant documents. In this case, it is possible to calculate a recall up to 0.4 (4 relevant documents retrieved on 10). How can they plot the points 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1?

Such examples are given in the Baeeza-Yates' Modern Information Retrieval book and by many others.

Answer (score 0):

You do not necessary need to return all available documents in order to have a recall of 1.

Using your example..
If you return 15 results with 10 relevant documents instead of 4 (and 10 are all the relevant documents in your collection), your recall will be 10/10=1.

Since the recall definition is:

recall = retrieved_relevant_documents / all_relevant_documents.

As you can also see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall

This metric is computed with a specific scenario (x relevant docs, y returned docs), probably in their plot, they are showing how the values change with a different number of relevant documents returned.